# Not able to capture the text from a span in selenium because of another tag present

Tags: selenium, innerhtml, gettext

When i capture the text by giving below code

```
String str1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@class='errorNotification']//span[2]")).getAttribute("innerHTML");

System.out.println("innerHTML: "+str1);
```

So i get the output like below

innerHTML:  `//i class="fa fa-times" style="font-size: 14px"></i Please enter user password!`

I want the text only "Please enter user password" and not the whole tag.

My DOM looks like

```
<div class="errorNotification">
    <span class="notificationCloseBtn" title="Close Notification">x</span>
    <span style="font-size: 13px">
        <i class="fa fa-times" style="font-size: 14px"></i>  Please enter user password!
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this :

```
String str1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@class='errorNotification']//span[2]")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

use this :

```
String str1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.errorNotification span.notificationCloseBtn+span")).getText()
System.out.println("Str 1 has : "  +str1);
```

**Explanation :**

You are using `getAttribute("innerHTML");` which will return `entire inner HTLM` (for the current node) with `HTML tags` and `text`, and it seems like you just want to grab the text, so Selenium has inbuilt method, `getText()` to retrieve the text between nodes.

Comment: Thanks, I tried with that but its giving me output blank, Str 1 has :       , nothing is appearing in the sysout.

Comment: okay, can you print this `String str1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.errorNotification span.notificationCloseBtn+span")).getText()` and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='errorNotification']/span[not(@class='notificationCloseBtn')]")).getText();
System.out.println(text);
```